# Nameserver not working, no A record found

Tags: nameserver, domain-name, a-record

I'm having trouble setting up a nameserver for my domain, we recently changed the nameserver of my domain because of an application that said our nameservers were not working fine. But now my domain does not respond to requests. I have no idea what were the last nameservers that were working. My domain is registered on Go Daddy, I did try to register my domain name to nameservers from zoneedit.com wich they say my domain has been correctly added to these nameservers : NS1.NAMERESOLVE.COM, NS2.NAMERESOLVE.COM, NS3.NAMERESOLVE.COM, NS4.NAMERESOLVE.COM which i put in Go Daddy nameserver setup. When i use intoDNS.com to check on my domain, i get 2 errors (which is a lot less than before, i use to have errors about the nameservers) :

MX - MX Records : Oh well, I did not detect any MX records so you probably don't have any and if you know you should have then they may be missing at your nameservers!

WWW - WWW A Record ERROR: I could not get any A records for www.datahex.ca!

(I only do a cache request, if you recently added a WWW A record, it might not show up here.)

An other thing is that my domain actually work for half my clients. My emails are not working.

So how can I fix this?

My domain is datahex.ca
I do have an other domain called datahex.com which works fine and is the same website and ip adresse has datahex.ca but is nameservers don't work with my other domain.

thank you.

Here is what i can do in dns manager on zoneedit.

DNS Management   help

```
datahex.ca     A     69.70.171.98        Delete
```

Sub Domain              Priority   Mail Server / MX
  datahex.ca
Only enter data in the                ____________   (Add new MX record)
 first field if you
need a MX record for a 
sub domain.

Sub Domain                              CName Server
  datahex.ca                            _____________     (Add new CNAME record)
Only enter data in the 
first field if you
need a CNAME record 
for a sub domain.

Sub Domain                                IP Address / A
  datahex.ca                              _____________     (Add new A record)

Only enter data in
 the first field if you
need a A record for
 a sub domain.

Sub Domain                             Text Record / TXT
  datahex.ca                           _______________  (Add new TXT record)

Only enter data in 
the first field if you
need a TXT record for 
a sub domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an A record for www if you want users to be able to get to www.datahex.ca and you need to create an MX record if you want users to be able to send you email. Your current name servers have neither.

In addition, you can create an A record for the domain itself as it also currently doesn't have one.

This information was obtained by querying ns1 - ns4.nameresolve.com directly.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, I know that I have to add an A record and mx record but when I did on the nameservers it simply didn't do a thing. how can i create an a record dirrectly on a domain? On Go Daddy settings? And how did you query ns1 - ns4 directly? I know tracert and nslookup but it didn't tell me any of that.

Comment: You have to add the records at the name servers for the domain, which are ns1 - ns4.nameresolve.com. Presumably you have access to a DNS control panel of some type at nameresolve.com (Dotster). GoDaddy is the registrar for your domain and lists your name servers primarily for WHOIS lookups, but your name servers have been moved to nameresolve.com so that's where you need to set up the DNS records. I queried those name servers directly by using nslookup with the command: server ns1.nameresolve.com, server ns2.nameresolve.com, etc. and then querying those servers for the appropriate records.

Comment: here is what i added in dns manager of zoneedit.com (added in question). But It dosen't seem to be doing anything. Maybe i'm understanding this the wrong way...

Comment: okay, my only problem now is that www.datahex.ca does not work but datahex.ca does! I did switch www from A records to CNAME. In my host file am I suppose to put the internal adresse or the public one? This is what my hosts look like: 192.168.200.11 www.datahex.ca 192.168.200.11 datahex.ca 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1 localhost

Comment: You need to add the public ip address not the private ip address.

Comment: great now my MX records is the only thing not working, I'll continue to search for that. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Glad to help...